# Axios + Vue помогите понять

Tags: vue.js, api, axios

Гуглил, смотрел видео уроки на ютубе, но так и не могу понять принцип работы с axios в vue.
Есть проект, где необходимо выгружать данные спортивной статистики через API, а я вообще не могу понять как.
Помогите, где можно почитать/посмотреть обучащий материал для чайника, желательно хороший практический пример.

Comment: axios никак не связан с Vue.js: берёте доки и читаете.
https://github.com/axios/axios#axios

Answer (score 0):

Axios — это JavaScript-библиотека для выполнения либо HTTP-запросов.
Vue.js — JavaScript-фреймворк с открытым исходным кодом для создания пользовательских интерфейсов.